# Find certain value in excel and add entire row below it using Vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

What i'd like to do, is write a VB macro that will scan the entire column (Column F) searing for "Year Total:" and then insert an entire row below it.

I have this:

Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a

```
Dim C As Variant
Dim FirstRow As Integer

With Worksheets(1).Range("F1:F4000")
    Set C = .Find("Year Total:", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        FirstRow = C.Row
        Do
            C.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Set C = .FindNext(C)
        Loop While Not C Is Nothing And C.Row <> FirstRow
    End If


End With
```

End Sub

However, it only adds cells in, not an entire row.

I'd also like to add into the code, for it to also search for "Grand Total:" in the same column and add three rows under it as well. I was just going to write two scripts, however if I can mash them all together in one, that would be excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here you go, I just tested it and this does the trick.  I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it, but it sounds like you're after a quick n' dirty solution so this hopefully works for you. :)

```
' Get last row
intLastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop till last row
intRow = 0
For Each strColFValue In ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F" & intLastRow).Value
    intRow = intRow + 1

    ' If found year, insert row below
    If InStr(UCase(strColFValue), "YEAR TOTAL:") > 0 Then
        Range("F" & intRow + 1).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert
        intRow = intRow + 1
    End If

    ' If found grand total, insert 3 rows below
    If InStr(UCase(strColFValue), "GRAND TOTAL:") > 0 Then
        Range("F" & intRow + 1).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert
        Selection.EntireRow.Insert
        intRow = intRow + 3
    End If

Next
```